# node js route not found

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have the following method to auth my users:

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    // CORS headers
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // restrict it to the required domain
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    // Set custom headers for CORS
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type,Accept,X-Access-Token,X-Key');
    if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
        res.status(200).end();
    } else {
        next();
    }
});

var auth = require('./auth.js');
router.post('/login', auth.login);
app.all('/api/*', [require('./middlewares/validateRequest')]);
// If no route is matched by now, it must be a 404
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
```

And my `Auth.js`

```
    var jwt = require('jwt-simple');

var auth = {

    login: function(req, res) {

        var username = req.body.username || '';
        var password = req.body.password || '';

        if (username == '' || password == '') {
            res.status(401);
            res.json({
                "status": 401,
                "message": "Invalid credentials"
            });
            return;
        }

        // Fire a query to your DB and check if the credentials are valid
        var dbUserObj = auth.validate(username, password);

        if (!dbUserObj) { // If authentication fails, we send a 401 back
            res.status(401);
            res.json({
                "status": 401,
                "message": "Invalid credentials"
            });
            return;
        }

        if (dbUserObj) {

            // If authentication is success, we will generate a token
            // and dispatch it to the client

            res.json(genToken(dbUserObj));
        }

    },

    validate: function(username, password) {
        // spoofing the DB response for simplicity
        var dbUserObj = { // spoofing a userobject from the DB.
            name: 'arvind',
            role: 'admin',
            username: 'arvind@myapp.com'
        };

        return dbUserObj;
    },

    validateUser: function(username) {
        // spoofing the DB response for simplicity
        var dbUserObj = { // spoofing a userobject from the DB.
            name: 'arvind',
            role: 'admin',
            username: 'arvind@myapp.com'
        };

        return dbUserObj;
    }
}

// private method
function genToken(user) {
    var expires = expiresIn(7); // 7 days
    var token = jwt.encode({
        exp: expires
    }, require('../config/secret')());

    return {
        token: token,
        expires: expires,
        user: user
    };
}

function expiresIn(numDays) {
    var dateObj = new Date();
    return dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + numDays);
}

module.exports = auth;
```

This server runs on port 8080.

So when i attempt to go to http://localhost:8080/login  i get the following error message:

```
    Error: Not Found
   at app.use.bodyParser.urlencoded.extended (/var/www/example/backend/server.js:34:15)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/example/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
   at trim_prefix (/var/www/example/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:302:13)
   at /var/www/example/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:7
   at Function.proto.process_params (/var/www/example/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
   at next (/var/www/example/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
   at next (/var/www/example/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:100:14)
   at next (/var/www/example/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
   at next (/var/www/example/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
   at next (/var/www/example/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
```

However it seems that the rest of my auth is working because if i go to:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/user
```

I get: `{"status":401,"message":"Invalid Token or Key"}`

Can anyone tell me why my login does not work?

**Full server script:**

```
    // BASE SETUP
// =============================================================================
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var es = require('express-sequelize');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

// =============================================================================

//Secure

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    // CORS headers
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // restrict it to the required domain
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    // Set custom headers for CORS
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type,Accept,X-Access-Token,X-Key');
    if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
        res.status(200).end();
    } else {
        next();
    }
});

var auth = require('./auth.js');
router.post('/login', auth.login);
app.all('/api/*', [require('./middlewares/validateRequest')]);
// If no route is matched by now, it must be a 404
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

var env = app.get('env') == 'development' ? 'dev' : app.get('env');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

// db config
var env = "dev";
var config = require('./database.json')[env];
var password = config.password ? config.password : null;

// initialize database connection
var sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.user,
    config.password,
    {
        logging: console.log,
        define: {
            timestamps: false
        }
    }
);

//Init models
var division_model = require('./lb_models/division/division_model')(express,sequelize,router);
var user_model = require('./lb_models/user/user_model')(express,sequelize,router);
var team_model = require('./lb_models/Team')(express,sequelize,router);

app.use('/api', router);
app.use(division_model);
app.use(user_model);
app.use(team_model);


// START THE SERVER
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Comment: Show the first 34 lines of server.js

Comment: @YuriZarubin added the whole script

Comment: Are you actually making a POST request when you visit the login page?

Comment: @HeadCode  i am using postman and yes its a post request

Comment: I updated my answer below.  It looks like you're not mounting your router at the right point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving your app.use(bodyParser…) statements above the login route.  The order of middleware matters.  At the time login is called the req object hasn't run through the bodyParser middleware yet.

Also, your router instance is mounted at "/api" so the router methods will never get called for "/login".  The following line should be place above your 404 catchall:

```
app.use('/', router);
```

Before, you had used app.use('/api', router), which means that your router routes will only be looked at for any request that starts with '/api'.  Also, you had place the 'use' statement too far down.

Comment: sadly this didnt change anything

Comment: Than you for your update however im not sure how to fix this? changing the auth path to api/login did not allow me to log in

Comment: thank you for your answer :) can you look at my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574012/node-js-post-authentication-req-username-password-is-undefined

Comment: @Marc Rasmussen Glad it worked.  And someone else got to your other question first.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

When setting up middleware, the order in which you call app.use() is key. In your server.js, you're setting up your application routes before you set up body parser. Meaning, when the request comes in, is is not parsed before hitting your application logic. You need to move the app.use(bodyParser) parts to the top of your code.

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var es = require('express-sequelize');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```

Comment: this did not change the outcome :(  updated the text

Answer (score 0):

perphaps you have to move the

```
app.use("/", (req, res, next) => {
  res.status("404").json({message: "Not found"})
})
```

to the bottom of your code, but before "app.listen()", The order you declare the routes in the router are important, so putting the "app.use" after you declare all theses routes, would search a match with all the previous route and if none is found then it will enter in that last one

Like this:

```
.
..
...
app.use('/api', router);
app.use(division_model);
app.use(user_model);
app.use(team_model);

app.use("/", (req, res, next) => {
  res.status("404").json({message: "Not found"})
})

// START THE SERVER
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```